# How to add some javascript in a form using form API?

Tags: 6, forms

I need to output some javascript codes as well as form fields.

I am using Drupal 6 and form API to build the form. How can I output those javascript codes? Is there a 'javascript' type like textfield/checkboxes ?

I have tried the code below but string 'Array' is printed on the page instead of js code:

```
$form['target'] = array(
'#prefix' => '<div id="newuser">' ,
'#value' => drupal_add_js('alert("hello)','inline'),
'#suffix' => '</div>'
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) is for adding script tags to the page.
It doesn't go in a form element.

```
 drupal_add_js('alert("Hello!")', 'inline');
```

would go by itself on a line. This would add that javascript to the page, so when the page loads you would get a pop-up that says "Hello".

and/or to add markup to the page you would do this:

```
$form['target'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="newuser">',
  '#value' => t('Hello'),
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

Which would add the text "Hello" to the form in the newuser div.